# How can I achieve this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I output the sample Record, that looks like in the Expected Result?

Sample Database

```
 Table Sample1
 Column Status      Int
 Column dtDateTime  dateTime
 Column User        varchar(50)
```

Records

```
 User     dtDateTime                   Status
 User1    2017-05-19 08:00:00.000      1
 User1    2017-05-19 17:05:00.000      2
 User1    2017-05-20 09:05:00.000      1
 User1    2017-05-21 17:35:00.000      2
```

The Record 1 as Time-IN and the Record 2 as Time-Out on the column status

Expected Result

```
 User         WORK-DATE      Time-IN         Time-OUT       Status
 user1        2017-05-19     08:00:00.000    17:05:00.000   COMPLETE
 User1        2017-05-20     09:05:00.000    NULL           NO OUT
 User1        2017-05-21     NULL            17:35:00.000   NO IN
```

Comment: can you explain how to get from the sample data to the expected result ?

Comment: what is the logic to determine Expected Result's Status?? you need to elaborate your question.

Comment: I'm assuming 1 is clock in and 2 is clock out, but we really need more clarification on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My crystal ball suggested this query:

```
SELECT   User, 
         CONVERT(DATE, dtDateTime) AS [WORK-DATE],
         CASE WHEN MIN(STATUS) <> MAX(STATUS) THEN 'COMPLETE'
              WHEN MAX(STATUS) = 1 THEN 'NO OUT'
              WHEN MIN(STATUS) = 2 THEN 'NO IN'
              END           
FROM     Sample1
GROUP BY User, CONVERT(DATE, dtDateTime)
```

EDIT : the crystal ball didn't show the TIME column earlier

```
SELECT   User, 
         CONVERT(DATE, dtDateTime) AS [WORK-DATE],
         MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN CONVERT(TIME, dtDateTime) END) AS [TIME-IN],
         MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 2 THEN CONVERT(TIME, dtDateTime) END) AS [TIME-OUT],
         CASE WHEN MIN(STATUS) <> MAX(STATUS) THEN 'COMPLETE'
              WHEN MAX(STATUS) = 1 THEN 'NO OUT'
              WHEN MIN(STATUS) = 2 THEN 'NO IN'
              END AS Status           
FROM     Sample1
GROUP BY User, CONVERT(DATE, dtDateTime)
```

Comment: You're a helpful squirrel, but it's worth considering that this platform has enough brazen requests for free labour without folks encouraging them to do so again. I would advise not answering questions where there is not a shred of prior effort.

Comment: Ha! Speak of the devil, the OP [made another request for free work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339750/how-to-create-a-query-for-this-scenario) five hours later. All they need to add on their post is "I've tried everything".