# How to create a query for this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried everything to make the Expected Result to show as an Output but No Luck.

Sample Database

Table1

```
 CalendarDate Date
```

Table2

```
User VarChar(50)
WDT DateTime
```

Table1 Records

```
 CalendarDate
 2017-01-01
 2017-01-02
 2017-01-03
 2017-01-04
```

Table2 Record

```
 WDT                         User
 2017-01-01 08:00:00.000     User1
 2017-01-02 08:05:00.000     USer1
```

Expected Result

```
 User     CalendarDate    Status     WDT            Time
 User1    2017-01-01      Present    2017-01-01     08:00:00.000 
 User1    2017-01-02      Present    2017-01-02     08:00:00.000
 User1    2017-01-03      Absent     Null           Null
 User1    2017-01-04      Absent     Null           Null
```

I want to show the date even if there is no record on Table2 and then display the status if the Table2 is null on Table1 CalendarDate

Comment: you should add what you want to achieve. From your example i guess you want to know for each user the presence/absence for all days in Table1?

Comment: I want to show the date even if there is no record on Table2 and then display the status if the Table2 is null on Table1 CalendarDate

Comment: how can you say User1 for 2017-01-03, 2017-01-04 dates, as those are not there in table2

Comment: select ... from table2 right outer join table1 ...

Comment: select  [status]=case when t1.calendardate=t2.wdt then 'Present' else 'Absent end'  from table1 as t1, table2 as t2

Comment: Harvy, you've made two requests on the same day that has (so far) netted you -5 and -3 in downvotes. These well-deserved votes are for asking other people to do your work for you. If you have tried something, please show it in the question, otherwise people won't believe you have made an attempt at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this to obtain a list for all the users (left join with table user in this case is not enough - see my sample data below):

```
SELECT C.USERNAME, A.CALENDARDATE
      , CASE WHEN B.USERNAME IS NULL THEN 'Absent' ELSE 'Present' END AS STATUS
      , CAST(B.WDT AS DATE) AS WDT, CAST(B.WDT AS TIME) AS TIME
FROM CALENDAR A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT USERNAME FROM US) C
LEFT JOIN US B ON A.CALENDARDATE = CAST(WDT AS DATE) AND C.USERNAME=B.USERNAME;
```

Sample data:

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd

CREATE TABLE CALENDAR (CALENDARDATE DATE);
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2017-01-01');
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2017-01-02');
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2017-01-03');
INSERT INTO CALENDAR VALUES ('2017-01-04');

CREATE TABLE US (USERNAME VARCHAR(10), WDT DATETIME);
INSERT INTO US VALUES ('User1', '2017-01-01 08:00');
INSERT INTO US VALUES ('User1', '2017-01-02 08:05');
INSERT INTO US VALUES ('User2', '2017-01-04 08:10');
```

Output:

```
   +----------+--------------+---------+------------+------------------+
| USERNAME | CALENDARDATE | STATUS  |    WDT     |       TIME       |
+----------+--------------+---------+------------+------------------+
| User1    | 2017-01-01   | Present | 2017-01-01 | 08:00:00.0000000 |
| User1    | 2017-01-02   | Present | 2017-01-02 | 08:05:00.0000000 |
| User1    | 2017-01-03   | Absent  | NULL       | NULL             |
| User1    | 2017-01-04   | Absent  | NULL       | NULL             |
| User2    | 2017-01-01   | Absent  | NULL       | NULL             |
| User2    | 2017-01-02   | Absent  | NULL       | NULL             |
| User2    | 2017-01-03   | Absent  | NULL       | NULL             |
| User2    | 2017-01-04   | Present | 2017-01-04 | 08:10:00.0000000 |
+----------+--------------+---------+------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

use a left join

```
select t1.CalendarDate, t2.[User], case when t2.[User] is null then 'Absent' else 'Present' end [Status], CAST(t2.wdt as date) WDT, CAST(t2.wdt as time) [Time]
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.CalendarDate = CAST(t2.wdt as date)

CalendarDate    User    Status  WDT         Time
2017-09-22      User1   Present 2017-09-22  11:23:19.2730000
2017-09-23      User1   Present 2017-09-23  11:23:19.2730000
2017-09-24      NULL    Absent  NULL        NULL
2017-09-25      NULL    Absent  NULL        NULL
```

if you need column [User] also for not matching rows you need to add a join with users table or extract users list from Table2 like:

```
select t1.CalendarDate, u.[User], case when t2.[User] is null then 'Absent' else 'Present' end [Status], CAST(t2.wdt as date) WDT, CAST(t2.wdt as time) [Time]
from Table1 t1
cross join (select distinct [User] from Table2) u
left join Table2 t2 on t1.CalendarDate = CAST(t2.wdt as date) and u.[User] = t2.[User]

CalendarDate    User    Status  WDT         Time
2017-09-22      User1   Present 2017-09-22  11:30:05.4800000
2017-09-23      User1   Present 2017-09-23  11:30:05.4800000
2017-09-24      User1   Absent  NULL        NULL
2017-09-25      User1   Absent  NULL        NULL
```

Comment: there is a null on the user this is not the expected Result

Answer (score 0):

A left join will do, but returns null values in user field, unless you hardcode it

```
select [USER],convert( varchar(10),t1.Calenderdate,120) Calenderdate ,
 case when convert( varchar(10),t2.WDT,120)  =  convert( varchar(10),t1.Calenderdate,120) then 'Present'
 else 'Absent' end Status, convert( varchar(10),t2.WDT,120) WDT,
 CAST(t2.WDT AS TIME) AS TIME 
 from 
 #tab1 t1 LEFT join #tab2 t2 on 
 convert( varchar(10),t2.WDT,120)  =  convert( varchar(10),t1.Calenderdate,120)
```

Comment: No there are incorrectly spelled like this one "Calenderdate" and also the User must not have a Null Value

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
        DECLARE @Table1 TABLE ([CalendarDate] DATE)
    DECLARE @Table2 TABLE ([User] VarChar(50), [WDT] DateTiME)

    INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES 
    ('2017-01-01'),
    ('2017-01-02'),
    ('2017-01-03'),
    ('2017-01-04')

    INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES
    ('User1', '2017-01-01 08:00:00.000'),
    ('User1', '2017-01-02 08:05:00.000')


    SELECT  ISNULL(t2.[User], 'User1') AS [User],
            t1.CalendarDate,
            CASE WHEN t2.[User] IS NOT NULL THEN 'Present' ELSE 'Absent' END AS Status,
            CAST(t2.WDT AS DATE) AS WDT,
            CAST(t2.WDT AS TIME) AS Time
    FROM @Table2 t2
    RIGHT JOIN @Table1 t1
    ON CAST(t2.WDT AS DATE) = t1.CalendarDate
```

Comment: ISNULL(t2.[empuser], 'User1') this one create a user which does not exists on the records

Comment: Yea, I know of course.. But its the output what he want. I thougt he will assume that he do not have data for that